# NaN в ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста в консоли выводит слово "Принят" а в mysql записывает NaN.
В чем может быть проблема?

```js
function go() {
var st = document.getElementById('div-03').previousElementSibling.value;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "editstatus.php",
      data: {
        status: +st
      },
      success: function(html) {
      }
    });
console.log(document.getElementById('div-03').previousElementSibling.value);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" value="Принят">
 <a id="div-03" onclick="go();">GO</a>
```

Comment: А зачем вы написали `+st`?

Comment: Что будет если `Принят` преобразовать в число? `NaN` естественно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`+` приводит строку принят к Number, вот что из этого получается:
```

```js
console.log(+"Принят");
```

вот `NaN` вы и отправили на сервер